# Converting NSString into const char

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have an String and i want to convert it into Const Char .
I Had tried but it's not Working

```
NSString *str4 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:character];
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Do like this:

```
NSString *strSQL = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

then something in your *strSQL

then this statement:

```
const char *bar = [strSQL UTF8String];
```

Comment: yep it's working fine but i had found another alternative for it sqlite3_bind_text();    but still there is a problem it works f9 with string but create problems with INTEGER Values.

Comment: tell me exactly what u want and what u are getting now then only i can try

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello";  

const char *cString = [myString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

or

```
const char * cstr2 = [ myString UTF8String ];
```

Comment: What's the difference between these two methods?  In the documentation, converting with `NSASCIIStringEncoding` mentions, *Returns NULL if the receiver cannot be losslessly converted to encoding*...

Answer (score 1):

You should use cStringUsingEncoding: method
Take a look at this method [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)